# In redux my action get called but not reducer, how can i resolve it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

just i'm trying to implement redux but i'm facing some issues with it.
my reducer not working i'm tracing it by putting console log everywhere
up to action it works proper after action control goes to the component not to reducer how can i resolve it.??

Comment: if you could share your code ?

Comment: More code please

Comment: Add your `combineReducers` code here...

Comment: Code would indeed be nice. It is probably because the action you are using is not wrapped in a dispatch. You can install Redux devtools to see more of what's going on. It will list all the dispatched actions for you, among other things.